# Ошибочное чтение

Tags: c++

Имею файл типа

```
name          x          y         m
OPV1    5995709.165 5563309.024 0.2121
OPV2    5994826.922 5561499.601 0.0894
OPV3    5994030.833 5561611.114 0.0322
OPV4    5993206.394 5561920.504 0.0322
```

Считываю:

```
ifstream file("data.txt");
    string name;
    double x, y;
    double m;
    while (file >> name >> x >> y >> m)
    {
        meas.push_back(Meas());
        meas.back().name = name;
        meas.back().m = m;
    }
```

В векторе meas первый элемент инициализируется как "п»їOPV1". Не могу разобраться в причине.

Полный код:

```
struct Meas {
    string name;
    double m;
};

        int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
        vector<Meas> meas;
        ifstream file("data.txt");
        string name;
        double x, y;
        double m;
        while (file >> name >> x >> y >> m)
        {
            meas.push_back(Meas());
            meas.back().name = name;
            meas.back().m = m;
        }
        //... 
    }
```

Comment: А что, уже есть такое число `double`, как `x`? :) У вас же первая строка текстовая! Там же не числа! Кстати, я бы сразу писал в вектор с использованием `.emplace_back()`, а не с вот этими извращениями через `.back()`...

Comment: Первую строку я добавил для наглядности, чтобы сразу было видно, что я подразумеваю под переменными. В самом файле их нет

Comment: Тогда давайте полный код... Что такое `Meas`, откуда вы знаете, как инициализирован вектор и так далее - из такого мелкого кусочка мало что понятно. Отладочный вывод делали? Или в отладчике смотрели? Что считывается в вашем цикле? Поставить перед `meas.push_back(Meas());` строку `cout << name << " " << m << endl;` - что выводится?

Comment: Смотрел в отладчике. Сейчас попробую Ваши рекомендации

Comment: У меня не воспроизвелось (VC++ 2017), все нормально работает.

Comment: Meas это структура, состоящая из имени и переменной m. Конкретно говоря меня не интересуют значения x,y. Далее вектор никак не инициализирован и используется в качестве базы для дальнейших математических вычислений. Если поставить перед meas.push_back(Meas()); строку cout << name << " " << m << endl; в имени выведется "п»їOPV1"

Comment: А, кажется, понял. Вероятно, файл в кодировке UTF-8, и впереди идут несколько байт, указывающих кодировку этого файла... Посмотрите его в каком-нибудь hex-редакторе...

Comment: Да, действительно, перед OPV1 были какие-то данные. К сожалению, я не разбираюсь в такиих вещах и потому не могу сказать, какую роль они выполняли . Однако с уверенностью могу сказать, что после их удаления программа считывает данные так, как задумывалось. Большое спасибо Harry за помощь!